# How to start a Foreground Service in Oreo and up after boot complete?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

I am working on an app in which I want to start a foreground service **after boot complete**. I know that I cannot start service in the broadcast that's why I am asking this question. I didn't found any useful detail to go forward. I am using a foreground service which provides me the location update after every minute.

For boot listening, I am using Broadcast-Receiver.

In `AndroidManifest.xml` I have written this.

```
<receiver
     android:name=".services.receiver.StartUpdateReceiver"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:exported="true"
     android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
     <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and after receiving boot receiver, I want to start the same Foreground service to get location updates after every minute. Which is working fine when I click on the button in activity to start foreground service to get location updates.

Please let me know the way how can I achieve this?

Comment: See this documentation https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

Comment: As per that doc:
*Background Service Limitations*: While an app is idle, there are limits to its use of background services. **This does not apply to foreground services**, which are more noticeable to the user.

That's why I want to use Foreground Service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `startForegroundService()` to start the foreground service.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, That worked but not as expected. I am not able to get location updates as you know there is also location update limit in Android O so how I can I handle this?

Comment: @HarishKamboj: A foreground service should not be affected: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Answer (score 1):

> Android 8.0 introduces the new method startForegroundService() to start a new service in the foreground. After the system has created the service, the app has five seconds to call the service's startForeground() method to show the new service's user-visible notification. If the app does not call startForeground() within the time limit, the system stops the service and declares the app to be ANR. As mentioned in Developers Site [Check this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background)